# Stray data byte in telnet negotiation. Where is it coming from?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, networking, telnet, tcpclient

I am using minimalistic telnet to backbone a telnet client though a forms project. I find that during the negotiation process the client sends the server a data byte of 37. If that were a IAC it would be for authenticating. There should be no data sent untill negotiations are done between the client and server.

I am stuck. Can someone help me figure out why this thing is auto sending a data byte of 37? This is what I found when using wireshark to sniff the packets. The Void Parsetelnet section is where the transmission is occurring.

Using Wireshark I see no instance of the server asking for an authentication option. So I am lost as to where the class is getting the byte 37. I need it to not send that.
Here is the class

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    namespace STC_Control
    {
        enum Verbs
        {
            WILL = 251,
            WONT = 252,
            DO = 253,
            DONT = 254,
            IAC = 255
        }

        enum Options
        {
            SGA = 3
        }

        class TelnetConnection
        {
            TcpClient tcpSocket;

            int TimeOutMs = 100;

            public TelnetConnection(string Hostname, int Port)
            {
                tcpSocket = new TcpClient(Hostname, Port);

            }

            public void WriteLine(string cmd)
            {
                Write(cmd + "\n");
            }

            public void Write(string cmd)
            {
                if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return;
                byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Replace("\0xFF", "\0xFF\0xFF"));
                tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            }

            public string Read()
            {

                if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return null;

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    do
                    {
                        ParseTelnet(sb);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
                    } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
                    return sb.ToString();

            }

            public bool IsConnected
            {
                get { return tcpSocket.Connected; }
            }

            void ParseTelnet(StringBuilder sb)
            {
                while (tcpSocket.Available > 0)
                {
                    int input = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                    switch (input)
                    {
                        case -1:
                            break;
                        case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                            // interpret as command
                            int inputverb = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                            if (inputverb == -1) break;
                            switch (inputverb)
                            {
                                case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                                    //literal IAC = 255 escaped, so append char 255 to string
                                    sb.Append(inputverb);
                                    break;
                                case (int)Verbs.DO:
                                case (int)Verbs.DONT:
                                case (int)Verbs.WILL:
                                case (int)Verbs.WONT:
                                    // reply to all commands with "WONT", unless it is SGA (suppres go ahead)
                                    int inputoption = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                                    if (inputoption == -1) break;
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Verbs.IAC);
                                    if (inputoption == (int)Options.SGA)
                                        tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WILL : (byte)Verbs.DO);
                                    else
                                        tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WONT : (byte)Verbs.DONT);
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)inputoption);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            sb.Append((char)input);
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Telnet Authentication Option](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2941.txt) “specifies the authentication option to the Telnet protocol as a generic method for negotiating an authentication type and mode, including whether encryption should be used and whether credentials should be forwarded.” [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc247790%28PROT.10%29.aspx)

There is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc247846%28PROT.10%29.aspx) on MSDN describing NTLM authentication session over Telnet.